# Unit testing a closure in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mockery

The closure in the code below has made this code very difficult to test.  How can I continue to eager load these items and maintain full testability?

```
public function scopeWithCompanyPreferences(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->with([
            'companies' => function ($query) {
                $query->with('companies');
                $query->with('preference_settings');
                $query->with('parent_company');
            }
        ]);
}
```

I've seen using Mockery the use of `Mockery::on()`, but I don't think that's useful given the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're mocking the `with` method, you should be able to use `Mockery::on()` like this:

```
$b = \Mockery::mock("your_builder_class");
$b->shouldReceive("with")
    ->with(\Mockery::on(function($x){
            // test $x any way you like, for example...
            // ...a simple check to see if $x["companies"] is a function
            return is_callable($x["companies"]);
        }))
    ->once()
    ->andReturn("hello!");
```

Comment: So what is tricky here is that the with method is actually accepting an array, where one of the array values is a closure.

Comment: The point of the `with()` method is to ensure that your code is being called with the arguments you expect - `Mockery::on()` allows you to write any test (as simple or as complicated as you like) to check those arguments.

Comment: That reference to the `with` method in my previous comment was intended to refer to `\Mockery::with`, not the `with` in your class. Sorry for any confusion.